# How to programmatically launch an OS X app in minimized mode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to launch my application on startup, but I want it to be "minimized", meaning, it will be opened in the dock but its window won't be displayed.

Same like TeamViewer, if you know this application.

I currently use `launchctl` with a plist I've added to `~Library\LaunchAgents`, and indeed on startup the application is launched, and its window is shown.

How can I launch it in such a **hidden / minimized** state?

Comment: the OP doesn't want to launch an app, he wants his app to be loaded minimized.

Comment: There is no concept of a "minimized application" in OS X. There are minimized windows, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncheck visible at launch in your xib for main application window.

[image]

Implement `- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag` in your app delegate class.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (!flag) {
        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Parag! However, I want to launch my app as minimized so that when the user will click on the icon in the Dock it will open. If I open it as hidden, the user can't open it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't... The app is hidden and whenever I click the Dock icon nothing happens...

Comment: As always @Parag to the rescue! Thanks! Worked like a charm after implementing applicationShouldHandleReopen.

Answer (score 0):

The below line will help you to achieve

[[self window] miniaturize:self];

Comment: no... that will launch it normally and then minimize the window

Answer (score 0):

minimized .. I think you want to launch it as HIDDEN

see NSWorkspace's :

`- (BOOL)launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options additionalEventParamDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)descriptor launchIdentifier:(NSNumber **)identifier`

use that to launch an app from another app and pass option `NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide`

---

if you wonder how you get the app to not show a dock icon:

define `LSUIElement = YES` in your plist

Comment: How do I use launchAppWithBundleIdentifier? I currently open the app in the launchctl and it automatically loads my MainMenu.xib...

Comment: thenn you don't want to programmatically launch an app ;)